# Opening an existing jQuery lightbox gallery from a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

I have an existing jQuery colorbox gallery that works fine when I click any of the 4 images which is initialized on document ready with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.gallery-thumbnail').length > 0) {
        $('.gallery-thumbnail').colorbox({ rel: 'gallery-thumbnail', transition: 'fade' });
    }
});
```

I also have a link in the page, which I would like to also open this same gallery of images.  I thought I would be cute and try to just replicate a user clicking one of the images with `$('.gallery-image').first().find('a').click();` which works perfectly and opens the image gallery when I type it in the Chrome Inline Console and hit `Enter`, but when it is run from the code, it just pops the gallery open with the orange loading GIF which spins endlessly.  After that I tried having an `onclick` handler directly on the HTML anchor which had the code `$('.gallery-thumbnail').colorbox({rel: 'gallery-thumb', transition: 'fade' });` which resulted in the same endless loading GIF as before.  To ensure that I wasn't going crazy, I hooked the `OnClick` event handler to a function which runs this code:

```
function showColorbox() {
    $('.gallery-thumbnail').each(function () {
        $(this).addClass('test');
    });
    $('.test').colorbox({rel: 'gallery-thumb', transition: 'fade' });
}
```

Unfortunately, I still end up with the endless loading colorbox, but I verified that my image anchors all had the class 'test'.  Throughout this whole thing - I have also verified that there are no JS errors in the console.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://jsFiddle.net would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an FAQ entry for this:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq/#faq-click

> **Create a separate link for opening a gallery**
>
> Lets say you've assigned Colorbox to a set of links in your document,
>   but you also want to have an "Open Gallery" link that opens the first
>   item in your set. When "Open Gallery" is clicked, you want to prevent
>   the default action, then trigger a click event on that first set item.

```
var $gallery = $("a[rel=gallery]").colorbox();
$("a#openGallery").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $gallery.eq(0).click();
});
```